# _setCustomVar equivalent for analytics.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is there a direct correspondence to any of the methods in analytics.js for the old `_setCustomVar` in ga.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, although it depends on your needs. It'll be one of the following:

```
ga('set', 'dimensionX', 'foobar');
// OR
ga('set', 'metricY', 501);
```

Replace X or Y with the number... remember you now have 20 of each for the free version. Quick and dirty difference: dimensions are the words (describes what it is) and metrics are the numbers of reports (how many / value).

Also, I created a [migration guide](http://misterphilip.com/universal-analytics/migration/) that covers most of the methods from GA -> UA. It should help you out!

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference

Here is the official reference for setting up dimensions and metrics in Google Analytics

And in bonus a good tutorial to set it up in Google Tag Manager thanks to Google Tag Manager & Data Layer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).